# Dockerfile is not working correctly in ARM Ubuntu 20

Tags: django, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-build, ubuntu-20.10

I am trying to build an image that works fine on mac on a ubuntu 20 virtual machine. on my host computer I run docker-compose --debug -f local.yml build and it works fine.

```
docker-compose --debug -f local.yml build
```

when I type the same command into ubuntu i get:

```bash
DEBU[0000] using default config store "/Users/lancemeister/.docker/buildx" 
[+] Building 3.9s (20/42)                                                                                      
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.85kB                                                                    0.0s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_local_django internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.90kB                                                                    0.0s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_production_postgres internal] load build definition from Dockerfile           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                       0.0s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs internal] load .dockerignore                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                          0.0s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_production_postgres internal] load .dockerignore                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                          0.0s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_local_django internal] load .dockerignore                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                          0.0s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim-bu  2.9s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_production_postgres internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/postgres:1  3.0s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                             0.0s
 => [auth] library/postgres:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                           0.0s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs internal] load build context                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 935B                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs python 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.10-slim-bullse  0.0s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_local_django internal] load build context                                     0.5s
 => => transferring context: 19.58MB                                                                      0.5s
 => CACHED [meister_affiliate_shop_local_django python-run-stage  1/11] WORKDIR /app                      0.0s
 => CANCELED [meister_affiliate_shop_local_django python-run-stage  2/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get   0.8s
 => ERROR [meister_affiliate_shop_local_django python-build-stage 1/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get ins  0.7s
 => ERROR [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs python-build-stage 1/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get insta  0.7s
 => ERROR [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs python-run-stage 1/7] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install  0.7s
 => [meister_affiliate_shop_production_postgres internal] load build context                              0.4s
 => => transferring context: 1.18kB                                                                       0.3s
 => CANCELED [meister_affiliate_shop_production_postgres 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/postgres:14@sha256:  0.6s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/postgres:14@sha256:cfd6203fc331bdf87ddf8c0ae91d9a6a6eacd5f2037c8178b644  0.0s
 => => sha256:f3ac85625e767ee0ec42b5a2ef93880251cd973b86f77124c4ed39bccd2f8bf9 0B / 30.06MB               0.7s
 => => sha256:378ffab63dc8bd21f2cd698be82bb12d9c0ba6aa5fbbc6c108b13721f37b2af8 0B / 4.42MB                0.7s
 => => sha256:036dbcdfa9cc43389f78510995735fd9a65dd14039d1b3c4303cfd33401e607d 0B / 1.80kB                0.7s
 => => sha256:cfd6203fc331bdf87ddf8c0ae91d9a6a6eacd5f2037c8178b644f1bbc369fafe 1.86kB / 1.86kB            0.0s
 => => sha256:0c29696257f7d05ad715f8415a40de4eeab35a8f74df2e418b06f30fd2808a4b 3.04kB / 3.04kB            0.0s
 => => sha256:af7af9ca355e4c01a4b9b0254b6bf811772fcc099d4d7ad445fb56d8f737ba9d 10.53kB / 10.53kB          0.0s
------
 > [meister_affiliate_shop_local_django python-build-stage 1/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y   build-essential   libpq-dev:
#0 0.644 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
------
 > [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs python-build-stage 1/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y   build-essential   libpq-dev   && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
#0 0.666 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
------
 > [meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs python-run-stage 1/7] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y   make   libpq-dev   gettext   && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
#0 0.696 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection                      
DEBU[0000] stopping session                              span="load buildkit capabilities"
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection                      
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection                      
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection                      
DEBU[0004] stopping session                              span=meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs
DEBU[0004] stopping session                              span=meister_affiliate_shop_local_django
DEBU[0004] stopping session                              span=meister_affiliate_shop_production_postgres
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y   make   libpq-dev   gettext   && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 1
```

local.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  meister_affiliate_shop_local_postgres_data: {}
  meister_affiliate_shop_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: meister_affiliate_shop_local_django
    container_name: meister_affiliate_shop_local_django
    platform: linux/arm64
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: meister_affiliate_shop_production_postgres
    container_name: meister_affiliate_shop_local_postgres
    volumes:
      - meister_affiliate_shop_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - meister_affiliate_shop_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  docs:
    image: meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs
    container_name: meister_affiliate_shop_local_docs
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/docs/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
    volumes:
      - ./docs:/docs:z
      - ./config:/app/config:z
      - ./meister_affiliate_shop:/app/meister_affiliate_shop:z
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: /start-docs
```

.compose/local/django/Dockerfile

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10-slim-bullseye

# define an alias for the specfic python version used in this file.
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION} as python

# Python build stage
FROM python as python-build-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local

# Install apt packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements .

# Create Python Dependency and Sub-Dependency Wheels.
RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels  \
  -r ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}.txt


# Python 'run' stage
FROM python as python-run-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local
ARG APP_HOME=/app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV BUILD_ENV ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

# Install required system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev \
  # Translations dependencies
  gettext \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# All absolute dir copies ignore workdir instruction. All relative dir copies are wrt to the workdir instruction
# copy python dependency wheels from python-build-stage
COPY --from=python-build-stage /usr/src/app/wheels  /wheels/

# use wheels to install python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/wheels/ /wheels/* \
    && rm -rf /wheels/

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start



# copy application code to WORKDIR
COPY . ${APP_HOME}

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

.compose/local/docs/Dockerfile

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10-slim-bullseye

# define an alias for the specfic python version used in this file.
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION} as python


# Python build stage
FROM python as python-build-stage

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements

# create python dependency wheels
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels  \
  -r /requirements/local.txt -r /requirements/production.txt \
  && rm -rf /requirements


# Python 'run' stage
FROM python as python-run-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # To run the Makefile
  make \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev \
  # Translations dependencies
  gettext \
  # Uncomment below lines to enable Sphinx output to latex and pdf
  # texlive-latex-recommended \
  # texlive-fonts-recommended \
  # texlive-latex-extra \
  # latexmk \
  # cleaning up unused files
  && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# copy python dependency wheels from python-build-stage
COPY --from=python-build-stage /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels

# use wheels to install python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/* \
  && rm -rf /wheels

COPY ./compose/local/docs/start /start-docs
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-docs
RUN chmod +x /start-docs

WORKDIR /docs
```

I would really apprieciate any help that i can get with problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, and it was that I was using an arm distribution I needed to choose containers that were also using the arm64 platform, and then it worked